# Upgrade Android version of Mediastar Diamond MS-X2 satellite receiver

Tags: updates

I have Mediastar Diamond MS-X2 4K with Android 7. 0 Nougat. After downloading the last upgrade file from the official site and restarting the device, it shows this error: "installation aborted".

What should I do?

Comment: You will need to contact MediaStar... these devices are not "standard" Android devices and use a specialized custom version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by USB :

1. You need to download the update file MS-Diamond-Z2_V3.4.1_2018-10-24 and put it on a USB drive in a folder
2. Then change both the name of the folder and the name of the update file to

   - Folder: `RomUpdate`
   - File: `RomUpdate`
3. Then turn on your Mediastar Z2 while you are pressing the Power button in front until the receiver screen shows an update
4. Then keep your hands away and the receiver will do the update automatically

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Going by your name here, it appears you are associated with Mediastar. If that is the case, please disclose your affiliation in the answer by [edit]. Thank you